# Is there a good page where mathematic papers are uploaded?

Tags: reference-request, online-resources

I am looking for a website where good math papers are uploaded that you can just read. I would like to read a little through the topics, but so far I have not really found a site that is clear and also provides free papers.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Have you looked at arxiv yet?

Comment: @Shiva no, so what is the link exactly?

Comment: It's [arxiv.org/](https://arxiv.org/).

Comment: ah wow perfect thanks!

Comment: Try [Project Euclid](https://projecteuclid.org/browse) and [this list by Sorin Popescu](http://www.math.stonybrook.edu/~sorin/elinks.shtml). I think all of those at Project Euclid are freely available, but a quick check showed that several (many?) of those in Popescu's list are behind paywalls (e.g. JSTOR and Springer are examples).

Comment: In my earlier comment I forgot about the French repository [NumDam](http://www.numdam.org/).

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro oh wow thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also check for archives that are specific to a given math area.

For example, if you are interested in Cryptography you can search here for papers (https://eprint.iacr.org/).